# Run SQL script in one transaction with SQLPlus

Tags: sql, oracle, transactions, sqlplus

Is there a way for SQLPlus to treat all commands in one transaction?

I have an sql file:

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT OFF

insert... ;
insert... ;
update... ;

commit;
exit;
```

The problem is only the update command gets updated, both inserts somehow get rollbacked. I assume that's because a semicolon terminates a transaction, and without autocommit it is rollbacked. How to run everything in one transaction in SQLPlus?

Comment: It is 1 transaction just as you show it. The semicolon indicates the end of a statement so SQLplus knows the statement can be executed after it reads the semicolon.

Comment: The semicolon does not "*terminate a transaction*". It marks the end of a statement.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by enclosing everything in

```
BEGIN ... END; / EXIT;
```

Still don't know why the original one didn't work.